# Kepp getting extra argument 'method' in call

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Been Scratching my head, Keep getting extra argument 'method' in call, All the data that I put is correct

`ratingStar` is a double data type

```
// Global Variable
reviewDriverEndPoint = "www.mywebsite.com/api/review"

func reviewDriver() {

        let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = [
            "star": ratingStar as AnyObject,
            "comment": reviewBox.text as AnyObject,
            ]
        Alamofire.request(reviewDriverEndPoint, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
            .responseJSON { response in
                if let value = response.result.value {
                   print(value)
                }
        }

}
```

Comment: and what's the problem?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error.

Answer (score 0):

Alamofire's method doesn't know if you pass variable or function as a parameter, so it uses the nearest local name (function in your case).

You have to change name of function or variable like

```
reviewDriverEndpoint = "www.mywebsite.com/api/review"

func reviewDriver() {

        let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = [
            "star": ratingStar as AnyObject,
            "comment": reviewBox.text as AnyObject
            ]
        Alamofire.request(reviewDriverEndpoint, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
            .responseJSON { response in
                if let value = response.result.value {
                   print(value)
                }
        }

}
```